Building an Unsatisfiable Set Over Fixed Atoms with All Pairs Satisfiable
Problem Statement
Consider a set of propositional formulas $M$ with the following properties:

$M$ contains exactly 3 formulas
All formulas in $M$ use the same set of atomic propositions
The formulas in $M$ cannot all be true simultaneously (i.e., $M$ is unsatisfiable)
Any subset of $M$ containing exactly 2 formulas is satisfiable

Find such a set $M$ and then extend your solution to create sets with $n$ formulas that have similar properties - the entire set is unsatisfiable,
but any subset of size 2 is satisfiable.
Interpretation
This differs from other similar questions asked before about an unsatisfiable set where each 2-element subset is satisfiable due to the restriction that forces us to use the same set of atomic propositions.
I would like to know if the following approach is correct and if it could be simplified.
3-element set example
For the 3-element set example, we'll use 3 atomic formulas $A_1$, $A_2$ and
$A_3$.
Firstly, we define the following 2 formulas:
$$
G_2 = A_1 \lor (\neg A_2 \land A_3)
$$
$$
G_3 = A_1 \lor (A_2 \land \neg A_3)
$$
The sub-index of $G$ represents the sole negated atomic formula in the
right hand part of the disjunction.
For the remaining formula, we'll define it as:
$$
L = \neg A_1 \land ((\neg A_2 \land A_3) \lor (A_2 \land \neg A_3))
$$
Now, we can say:
$$
M = \{G_2, G_3, L\}
$$
Let's verify every possible 2-element subset is indeed satisfiable:
For $\{G_2, G_3\}$, we see that any interpretation in which $A_1$ holds is a
model for this subset.
Then, for $\{G_2, L\}$, $\neg A_1$ must hold (since it's the left part of
the conjuntion of $L$), so the right-hand side of the disjunction of $G_2$
must hold too. We conclude our model is:
$$
\{\neg A_1, \neg A_2, A_3\}
$$
Lastly, for $\{G_3, L\}$ we follow a similar reasoning to the previous
subset. Which leads us to:
$$
\{\neg A_1, A_2, \neg A_3\}
$$
We have now concluded every 2-element subset is satisfiable.
For the solution to be correct, $M$ should be unsatisfiable. This is the
case because in order for an interpretation to be a model of $M$,
it would have to make $\neg A_1$ hold, which would force the right
hand part of both $G_2$ and $G_3$ to hold simultaneously.
Said interpretation does not exist so $M$ is indeed unsatisfiable.
Generalization to $n$ elements
To generalize to sets of $n$ elements, we'll define $S_k$:
$$
S_k = (\neg A_k \land \bigwedge_{i=2,i\neq k}^n A_i)
$$
$S_k$ allows us to define, for an arbitrary number $k$, a sequence
of conjunctions where only $A_k$ is negated.
We can use this expression to obtain $G_k$:
$$
G_k = A_1 \lor S_k
$$
And lastly, to define $L$, which is the formula that can form a
satisfiable group with only one $G_k$ at a time, we'll also use $S_k$.
$$
L = \neg A_1 \land (\bigvee_{k=2}^n S_k)
$$
So, the example for $n$ elements will be:
$$
M = \{G_2, \ldots, G_n, L\}
$$
